# Where am I going wrong in this ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I've got an ODE of the form $$y'(x) = \pm \left(\frac yB-1\right)^{1/2}$$

Here's how I do it:

$$y'(x) = \pm\left(\frac yB-1\right)^{1/2} \\ \implies \int\frac{dy}{\left(\frac yB-1\right)^{1/2}}=\pm\int dx = \pm x+C$$

Now let $y=B\cosh(u)$, then $dy=B\sinh(u)du$.  So

$$\implies \int \frac{B\sinh(u)du}{(\cosh(u)^2-1)^{1/2}} = Bu = B\operatorname{arccosh}\left(\frac{y}{B}\right) \\ \implies y=B\cosh\left(\frac{\pm x+C}{B}\right)$$

However, [WolframAlpha solves the ODE and gets a simple quadratic](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27(x)%3Dsqrt(y%2FB-1)).  Where have I made a mistake?

Comment: You don't need to use a substitution with a hyperbolic function ... setting $y/B = u$ will do fine.

Comment: Yep.  Silly mistake.  I'm so used to seeing $$\frac{1}{\left[\left(\frac yB\right)^{\textbf{2}}-1\right]^{1/2}}$$ that I didn't notice the $2$ wasn't there this time.  Whoops!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> $$y'(x) = \pm\left(\frac yB-1\right)^{1/2} \\ \implies \int\frac{dy}{\left(\frac yB-1\right)^{1/2}}=\pm\int dx = \pm x+C$$

$$\int\frac{dy}{\left(\frac yB-1\right)^{1/2}}=2B\sqrt{\left(\frac yB-1\right)}$$

$$2B\sqrt{\left(\frac yB-1\right)}=\pm x+C$$
$$4B^2\left(\frac yB-1\right)=x^2+C\pm 2Cx$$

Since $$\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{ax}}=2\frac{1}{a}\sqrt{x}$$

Comment: Oh Jeez!  I just realized that $y$ wasn't squared under in the denominator so what I did with the cosh function wouldn't work.  Thanks.